# Externalize configuration of Spring Boot microservices using Netflix Archaius with config files in github repo

Tags: java, spring-boot, github, config, netflix-archaius

I have recently been given a task to externalize the configuartions of springboot microservices using Netflix archaius. I had gone through the official Wiki page of Netflix-Archaius but it does list some features such as storing Configuration file locally or storing the configuration in a DB and connect using JDBC, etc.

Now the configurations of my microservices are stored in `/src/main/resources`
folder and i need to externalize these configuartions.

I want to know if it is possible to store the properties files in a github repo and dynamically load the configuration from the repo on runtime.

Some of the links that i have referred are given below:

https://github.com/Netflix/archaius/wiki/Getting-Started

https://jlordiales.wordpress.com/2014/10/07/configuration-management-with-archaius-from-netflix/

I had found a similar configuration manager **Spring-cloud-config-server** which can use github repo for storing the config files but i need to implement this using Netflix-Archaius.